# A more elegant way to copy std::string into a vector<char>

Tags: c++

I can't see to find the answer to this, so sorry in advance if there is a duplicate.

#### Is there a more elegent way of creating a `vector<char>` from a `string`.

```
std::string s("I'm afraid. I'm afraid, Dave.");
std::vector<char> temp;                        
for (size_t x = 0; x < s.size(); x++)          
{                                              
    temp.push_back(s[x]);                      
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Construct a range with an iterator like this:

```c++
std::vector<char> temp(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::copy()`:

```
std::copy( std::begin( string ) , std::end( string ) , std::back_inserter<char>( vector ) );
```

Or use the overload of the `std::vector` ctor which takes a range to be initializated with:

```
std::vector<char> vector{ std::begin( string ) , std::end( string ) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
std::string str = "I'm afraid. I'm afraid, Dave.";
std::vector<char> data(str.begin(), str.end());
```